# How can I find the value of a blury image Matlab question

Tags: matlab

Is there a method to detect the value of a image rgb that is blury?

I simply want to store the blury value of my image in a variable called blury value? Is there a dedicated function?

```
%image1 which is rgb is stored in variable img1

img1 = imread('102.jpg');

% conversion to grayscale stored in img1_grey variable

img1_grey = rgb2gray(img1);

blury_value = function_matlab(img1)
```

So is a value that indicates me how blur is my image.

If my image is very blur he must have a value higher.

So I search a method to store the value that indicates how my rgb image is blur so the value that indicates the level of my blur image.

I found an article here that use edge detection and the level of the degree of my image if it's blured or not.

Also it says that I must use HWT algorithm. I searched on google blur detection for digital images using using wavelet transform and it's the first pdf.

Comment: what a blurry question.

Comment: I need this information I searched the function in Image Processing of Matlab. I need to know if I can store the value that indicates the degree of my blury image using a matlab function. The blury value will be stored in variable blury_value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you define 'blurry value', please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some metric of blurriness.  Coding it in Matlab once it's been defined should be the easy part.

Comment: You can make this by means of fourrier wavelet coefficient and a approximation that is non-linear. Signal noise report SNR describe this coefficient I found it.

I found an interesting link here:

http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/numerical-tour/tours/introduction_fourier_wavelets/

Now my problem is that I don't know how to find this function that is used for:

perform_wavelet_transf  I didn't have it and it gives me this error:

Here is the full source:

http://www.mediafire.com/?qnzwnw3wjom